# Chat app list last messages of each peer using parse server

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I am doing a chat app using parse server, everything is great but i tried make to list just last message for every remote peer. i didn't find any query limitation how to get just one message from every remote peer how can i make this ?

Answer (score 1):

> Query limitation with [Parse SDK](http://parseplatform.org/)

To limit the number of object that you get from a query you use [limit](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/2.4.0/Parse.Query.html#limit)

Here is a little example:

```
    const Messages = Parse.Object.extend("Messages");
    const query = new Parse.Query(Messages);
    query.descending("createdAt");
    query.limit(1); // Get only one result
```

> Get the first object of a query with [Parse SDK](http://parseplatform.org/)

In you case as you really want only one result you can use [Query.first](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/2.4.0/Parse.Query.html#first).
Like [Query.find](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/2.4.0/Parse.Query.html#find) the method [Query.first](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/2.4.0/Parse.Query.html#first) make a query and will return only the first result of the [Query](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/2.4.0/Parse.Query.html)

Here is an example:

```
    const Messages = Parse.Object.extend("Messages");
    const query = new Parse.Query(Messages);
    query.descending("createdAt");
    const message = await query.first();
```

I hope my answer help you

Comment: thanks for answer i know that setting limit for query but it is not enough for me beacuse i need to set limit every remote peer when i get to objects for list messages with everybody

Comment: What do you mean by remote peer ?

Comment: for example [link](https://prnt.sc/nvhemi) you can look this image for understand. I want to list the people you talked to in the past with last messages

Comment: Makes sense I understand now, can you show me how did you manage your database ?

Comment: I want to see the table of User and the table of messages

Comment: Hello @Julien Kode i dont save any message object in user class, i created a new class "Message", i save sender and remote user data, message as like image [link](https://prnt.sc/nw4pcg)

Comment: Yes nice, did you save the userObjectId or you create a relation ?

Comment: of course i saved, as you can see i save parse user who sent message and i save their object id in an array, i can get their object id from 'local' or 'remote' columns
`
ParseUser user = object.getParseUser('local' or 'remote');
String objectId = user.objectId;
`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using a single query, you will have to use aggregate:
https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#aggregate

Try something like this:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Messages");
var pipeline = [
  { match: { local: '_User$' + userID } },
  { sort: { createdAt: 1 } },
  { group: { remote: '$remote', lastMessage: { $last: '$body' } } },
];
query.aggregate(pipeline)
  .then(function(results) {
    // results contains unique score values
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // There was an error.
  });
```

Comment: that's exactly what I want, i'll try thank you so much :)

Comment: can i make to this using distinct on queries ?

Comment: I don't think so. Have you tried the query that I suggested?

Comment: I didn't clearly understand aggregate. [thats my messages class](prnt.sc/pbzrfv)

Comment: I could use to aggregation after reading the mongo documentation. thanks for saved my life :)